# Exception calculating eigenvalues in numeric.js

Tags: javascript, eigenvalue

I'm facing a strange issue while using the *eig* method of the [numeric.js](http://www.numericjs.com/documentation.html) library, that method is used to calculate the eigenvalues of square matrixes. If the size of the matrix is 4 or 5 the method calculats the eigenvalues without any problem, when the size is 6 I get an

```
Uncaught Error: eig: internal error
  at Function.numeric.house (VM145 numeric.min.js:1)
  at Function.numeric.QRFrancis (VM145 numeric.min.js:1)
  at Function.numeric.QRFrancis (VM145 numeric.min.js:1)
  at Function.numeric.eig (VM145 numeric.min.js:1)
  at js:32
```

I created a small script that replicates the issue using square matrixes of different sizes.

```js
ns = [4,5,6]

for (var h=0; h<ns.length; h++){
  matr = []
  n = ns[h]
  for (var i=0; i<n; i++){
    row = []
    for (var j=0; j<n; j++){
      row.push(1)
    }
    matr.push(row)
  }
  
  eigenvalues = numeric.eig(matr)
  console.log(eigenvalues.lambda.x)
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeric/1.2.6/numeric.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
Nothing to see here, look at your console.
</body>
```

Is anybody facing the same issue? Any idea for a workaround?

Comment: Could it be related to this? https://github.com/sloisel/numeric/issues/50

Comment: I wouldn't recommend on using that library at all. It seems the author has died, at least he's ignoring all and everything related since  2013.

Comment: As for a workaround, I used a 6x6 matrix of something other than all 1's and it seems to work ok. `[[1,2,5,1,2,5],[3,5,-1,3,5,-1],[7,-3,5,7,-3,5],[1,2,5,1,2,5],[3,5,-1,3,5,-1],[7,-3,5,7,-3,5]]`. Linear algebra was a long time ago, so I apologize if this is an invalid matrix.

Comment: Definitely related to the issue posted by the @callback I don't know what to do now, I need another library for calculating eigenvalues consistently and it looks like there is nothing for JavaScript.

Comment: Is this any good to you? http://mathjs.org/examples/import.js.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the numeric.js library. It can solve well-posed matrices like this:

```
numeric.eig([[1, 0.5],[0, -1.4]]);
```

gives the result:

```
 x: [ -1.4000000000000004, 1.0000000000000002 ]
```

However numeric.js fails to solve eigenvalues for this one -

```
matrix = 
[
  [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ]
]
```

I tried a number of similar binary / sparse matrices and got internal errors such as in your question.

The comments suggested alternatives like the mathjs library. I tried that and several other libraries without success before finding a more robust option.

1. mathjs - eigenvalue decomposition limited to symmetric real matrices.
2. sylvester-es6 - returns a vector of NaN eigenvalues for most binary matrices I tried.
3. eigen - poor documentation, never figured out how to instantiate the Solver object.
4. jamaJS - works in theory but requires several external dependencies such as Java 8 JDK and Maven.
5. CindyJS - not available on NPM
6. LALOlib - not available on NPM
7. linear-algebra does not include eigenvalue decomposition
8. linear-algebra-js does not include eigenvalue decomposition

Quite a frustrating afternoon. Fortunately I ended up running across this library in a Reddit thread:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ml-matrix

This library finally solved my problem:

```
const mlMatrix = require('ml-matrix');
const M = new mlMatrix.Matrix(matrix);
const e = new mlMatrix.EigenvalueDecomposition(M);

e.realEigenvalues -> [-1.4142135623730945, 2.220446049250313e-16, 1.4142135623730954, 0, 0, 0 ]
e.imaginaryEigenvalues -> [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Setting a reasonable zero tolerance such as 1e-10 takes care of the rounding error.